# Prevent rows from filling the height of the grid container

Tags: css, css-grid

Similar—but not exactly—questions have been asked. In a container set to a min-height, the rows in the grid are 1) implicit, and 2) expanding vertically to the height of the container. I want each element to have its natural height.

In this [CodePen](https://codepen.io/breadwild/pen/MWEKxoV) you can see what I mean. If the height of the container: `80vh` is removed, the elements resume their natural height, but my footer then moves up from the bottom of the portal.

Not sure what is going on here. Thoughts?

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}

main.chapter {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  min-height: 80vh;
}

.column {
  grid-column: 1 / 5;
  background: beige;
  border: 1px solid #999;
}

form {
  grid-column: 1 / 3;
  background: beige;
  border: 1px solid #999;
}

.table-list {
  grid-column: 1 / 4;
  background: beige;
  border: 1px solid #999;
}

footer {
  background-color: tan;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 30px;
  min-height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<main id="primary" class="chapter" itemprop="page">

  <div class="column">
    <h1>Test Page</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent tincidunt imperdiet justo, ac rhoncus urna sollicitudin vitae. Duis eu dolor eu dui tempor cursus. Phasellus sit amet velit sit amet metus accumsan rhoncus. </p>

    <p>Below are links to a number of homilies preached at New Melleray and Our Lady of the Mississippi by members of our community.</p>
    </p>
  </div>

  <form>
    <p>Name: <br><input type="text"></p>
    <p>Gender: <br><input type="text"></p>
    <p>Age: <br><input type="text"></p>
    <p>Email: <br><input type="text"></p>
  </form>

  <div class="table-list">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Suspendisse tortor ligula</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Suspendisse tortor ligula</td>
        </tr>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>

</main>

<footer id="colophon" class="site-footer">
</footer>
```

Comment: So simple! Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

The [default setting for implicit rows](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#auto-tracks) is `grid-auto-rows: auto`, which will cause rows to consume equal space.

Override the default with `grid-auto-rows: min-content`.

Add this to your code:

```
main.chapter {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
    max-width: 600px;
    margin: 20px auto;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    min-height: 80vh;
    grid-auto-rows: min-content; /* NEW */
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}

main.chapter {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  min-height: 80vh;
  grid-auto-rows: min-content; /* NEW */
}

.column {
  grid-column: 1 / 5;
  background: beige;
  border: 1px solid #999;
}

form {
  grid-column: 1 / 3;
  background: beige;
  border: 1px solid #999;
}

.table-list {
  grid-column: 1 / 4;
  background: beige;
  border: 1px solid #999;
}

footer {
  background-color: tan;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 30px;
  min-height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<main id="primary" class="chapter" itemprop="page">

  <div class="column">
    <h1>Test Page</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent tincidunt imperdiet justo, ac rhoncus urna sollicitudin vitae. Duis eu dolor eu dui tempor cursus. Phasellus sit amet velit sit amet metus accumsan rhoncus. </p>

    <p>Below are links to a number of homilies preached at New Melleray and Our Lady of the Mississippi by members of our community.</p>
    </p>
  </div>

  <form>
    <p>Name: <br><input type="text"></p>
    <p>Gender: <br><input type="text"></p>
    <p>Age: <br><input type="text"></p>
    <p>Email: <br><input type="text"></p>
  </form>

  <div class="table-list">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Suspendisse tortor ligula</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Suspendisse tortor ligula</td>
        </tr>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>

</main>

<footer id="colophon" class="site-footer">
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried `display: flex` and same issue—elements stretch vertically to fill up the container.

So, I wrapped the 3 elements with another div, removed the `display: grid` from the original wrapper and applied it to the new. Cheating? Maybe. However, it just might be the correct approach.

Original:

```
<main id="primary" class="chapter">
    <div class="column">...</div>
    <form>...</form>
    <div class="table-list">...</div>
</main>

main.chapter {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
    grid-row-gap: 0.5rem;
    max-width: 600px;
    margin: 20px auto;
    min-height: 80vh;
}
```

Revised:

```
<main id="primary" class="chapter">
    <div class="wrapper"> <!--added -->
        <div class="column">...</div>
        <form>...</form>
        <div class="table-list">...</div>
    </div>
</main>

main.chapter {
    max-width: 600px;
    margin: 20px auto;
    min-height: 80vh;
}
.wrapper {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
    grid-row-gap: 1.0rem;
}
```